# scp not working in cronjob

Tags: ssh, bash

On a CentOS setup I have a script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
mysqldump --all-databases | gzip > /dumps/sql`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%$
scp `ls -t | head -1`  root@backup:/media/storage/backup/
```

The machine is configured with an authorized ssh key so a password is not necessary. If I run it (/bin/bash mysql.sh) it works as intended, but in a cronjob only the mysqldump is carried out. The scp command fails.

Where do I look to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `scp` doesn't pick up your key pair from `~/.ssh` directory. Try this:

`env HOME=/path/to/your/home scp -v $(ls -t | head -1)  root@backup:/media/storage/backup/ > /tmp/scp.log 2>&1`

If it doesn't work, post the `scp.log` here.

Comment: Thx, I'll look into that.

Comment: the scp.log says: debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /media/storage/backup/
dumps: not a regular file
Sink: ^Ascp: dumps: not a regular file
Where 'dumps' is the folder the script is located in. Apparently the 'ls -t | head -1' part doesn't work. Authentication works ok.

Comment: Try using `scp -r` to copy a folder.

Comment: There's about 30 backup files in the folder, so I'd prefer to just copy 1 :-) Problem was the path; if I specify the full path it works. Not the cleanest solution but for now it works.

Comment: It does pick up the key btw, even without home folder specified.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases scripts which work from the command line but not from cron fail due to environment issues.  If you are using ssh agent or otherwise setting information scp needs to function in your environment, you'll need to explicitly set them in your script or source your .bashrc (or whatever file sets your variables.); cron does not use your rc files by default, so your environment is quite bare.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, first of all, you should check your cron's logs for errors, maybe you can copy a little part of your logs here to have a better troubleshooting.

You might try to change the "date" command with this:

> $(date +\%F)

And than try again to set the cronjob ;-)

Comment: The problem is not the date part; that works ok. There is a c/p error in the OP, but the file is created correctly. Just scping that doesnt work.

Comment: I think that scp can't find the ssh key. maybe you should check your key location